# Accessing VM drives using TimeTrigger Function App

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy, azure-function-app

I have a requirement where i need to delete some files from Azure VM drive. I created FunctionApp (Time Trigger) that will check and delete files from drive folder. I also integrated Function APP with Azure VM VNET. Yet i am getting exception of Access is denied while running Function APP. Is there way to connect Function APP with Azure VM drive (folder under drive.)

Created Function App
Created VNET
Created VM and integrate with VNet
Integrated FunctionAPP with VNet

Function App should run and access drives of VM

Comment: Can you show the code ? Provide more error information

Comment: Basically i am trying to delete files in one of the folder that lies in F drive of VM. I created timer trigger function app and integrated with VNet which VM is integrated with. I have created app setting with value of  server IP followed by folder path. When code try to access the path it throws exception of "Access is denied". I am not sure what else we need to do to access VM folders in F drive.

Comment: You could try share your folder then access it.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure the VNET with function app , The function app will able to access the virtual network .

If there are any issue in this,follow this doc which discuss about step by step instruction

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet

Then **Create a proxy to access VM resources** . With VNet Integration enabled, you can create a proxy in your function app to forward requests to the VM running in the virtual network.

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet#create-a-proxy-to-access-vm-resources**